# Sona: how complete it is and how alive it is?

Tags: speech-communities

I find the basic ideas of [Sona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sona_language_(artificial)) very appealing, but, from what I see in the web, it is not, by far, as popular as Esperanto or Lojban or other well-known conlangs. Therefore my question: Is it a complete language with a community of fluent speakers, translations of literary works available..? Or is it basically dead?

Answer (score 4):

**I think it's pretty much dead**.

There is~was a [Yahoo group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/sona_language/info). It has 80 members and no recent activity. But Yahoo groups are all screwed up now, so it's difficult to tell.

There is a dead Sona [forum](http://sonasokasama.proboards.com) with 14 members. There are a couple translations. No activity since 2010.

There is a dead Sona [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/sonagona) with 13 members. No activity since 2013.

There is a dead Sona [tutorial website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DzI3RPFV4oQJ:www.sonagona.org/%20&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=opera) archived by the Wayback Machine. Not reachable by ordinary means.

The grammar book was hosted online in a now defunct location [archived by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110720131906/http://www.rickharrison.com/language/sonabook.html).